# Finding distribution of $X+Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Two dimensional random variable has uniform distribution on a square.
$$K=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|+|y|\le1\}$$
Find a distribution of $X+Y$.
How to find this distribution? I know answer is $\frac{1+t}{2}$ for $t\in[-1,1]$ and 1 for $t \ge 1$, but why is that?

Comment: hint: $\Pr[X+Y \le t]$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The probability $P(X+Y\le t)$ is equal to the ratio of the area of the rectangle $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:|x|+|y|\le1\}$ that is below the line $y=t-x$ to the whole area of the rectangle. If $t=0.5$, we have the folowing graph.
[image]

The whole area of the rectangle is equal to $\sqrt 2\sqrt 2=2$ and the area below the line the line $y=t-x$ is equal to $1+t$. Hence, we have that 
$$
P(X+Y\le t)=
\begin{cases}
0, &\text{if}\, t<-1;\\
\frac{1+t}2, &\text{if}\, -1\le t\le 1;\\
1,&\text{if}\, t>1.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Appreciate your effort! Thank you!

Comment: @mkropkowski You're welcome!

Comment: I thought i understood everything but i was wrong, why do we divide by two?

Comment: @mkropkowski Since the distribution is uniform, the probability of an event that is represented by some subset of this square is equal to the ratio of the area of the subset to the area of the whole square. The area of the square is equal to $\sqrt 2\sqrt 2=2$. Hence, we divide by $2$. The area below the line $y=t-x$ is equal to $\sqrt 2\frac{1+t}{\sqrt 2}=1+t$. So the final answer is $(1+t)/2$.